# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: c#, encryption

I trying to Decrypt password in visual studio 2010 using C-Sharp language but i m stuck on this error i try all the solution which was provided on this side but my error not resolved how i encrypt password can anybody tell me using MD5 my code is,Now it gives another error **"String reference not set to an instance of a String.**Parameter name: s"*** What can i do i cant understand .I m newbie on C#*.I dont know what can i do if i waste your time then sorry to all.

```
     public string PasswordDecrypt(string sQueryString)
        {

            byte[] buffer;
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider loCryptoClass = new
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider loCryptoProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();


            try
            {
                buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sQueryString);
                loCryptoClass.Key = loCryptoProvider.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sQueryString));
                loCryptoClass.IV = lbtVector;
                return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(loCryptoClass.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                loCryptoClass.Clear();
                loCryptoProvider.Clear();
                loCryptoClass = null;
                loCryptoProvider = null;
            }



            }
```

Comment: Please cut down this wall of code to a short 10-15 line complete program that demonstrates the problem. We don't want to wade through all the stuff that we don't need to see.

Comment: where is the error? md5 doesn't do encryption, it hashes.

Comment: @Ankush hashing is one-way encryption.

Comment: @CodeCaster And following this, MD5 is no encryption, but a hash function. The definition of encryption is:
A convertion into ciphertext which can be reconverted into its original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code relevant to your question is this:

```
string sQueryString = txtPassword.Text;
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sQueryString);
```

Create a test case for this, containing the data as is entered when you get the error. Perhaps your users don't input their password as base64.

Comment: @Raheel that's because "786" **is no base64 string** (valid characters, but the length is incorrect). You dump a lot of code and say it doesn't work. Please explain in your question what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about what to do for password security. Passwords don't get encrypted, they get hashed. That's kind of a one-way-encryption. The same password will always result in the same hash, but different passwords are allowed to generate the same hash, so it's impossible to decrypt it from hash to password.

While that doesn't sound useful at first, the point is that you never actually store the password, encrypted or not. You store the hash value of the password. That way you know when someone enters a password, it gets hashed and matches the stored hash, it's the correct password... without ever knowing what the password *was*.

So you cannot decrypt a hash. You simply hash your input and compare with an earlier hash from the correct password.

Please note that you should also google `Salting` hashes, a technique for lowering the attack surface of hashes once the data store was breached and the hash is known to potential attackers.